# Provide summary of container like tableview with Voice Over

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to enable voice over for a tableview with a few standard cells. I've configured the cell views to have the appropriate accessibilityLabel and trait, but I'm stuck trying to implement the following behaviour:

When the table view is in focus, it should say: "Recipes List, 16 elements", then move to the first entry. I wonder how this could be accomplished?

Apple does something similar in the weather app. If Voice Over is active and you scroll to the details section (sun rise, sun set, humidity etc), it will say "Details, sun rise ...". When you tap directly onto the label however, it will say "sun rise, ..." (without "Details").

One workaround I thought of is to add the text to the first cell, but that feels a bit hacky, since the label logically belongs to the table view, not the cell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I came here looking for the exact same solution (to mirror the weather app). did you ever have any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

A container and its children cannot be accessible all together *(explanation [here](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements))*.

I think that a custom accessibility element should overlap the table view *(both with the same frame)* and ordering must have been setup in order to read out the new view before the first cell of the table view.

The table view is definitely not read out if its cells are accessible with VoiceOver.

This is just an assumption because I can't find the behavior you mentioned for the Apple weather app.